# How to import a crate dependency when the library name is different from the package name?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a crate that is imported straight off of GitHub, as per Cargo's [documentation](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html):

```
[dependencies]
libfoo = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/me/libfoo", branch = "dev" }

[lib]
path = "src/rust/lib.rs"
name = "myprj"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

Running `cargo build` works fine here, Cargo fetches `libfoo` and builds it in the `~/.cargo` directory. When I try to use (import) it in `lib.rs`:

```
extern crate libfoo;   //also tried foo
```

Cargo chokes:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `libfoo`
 --> src/rust/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate libfoo;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

Interestingly, IntelliJ's Rust plugin does find the crate when I click on it in `lib.rs` – it navigates to the downloaded source in `~/.cargo`...

In the dependency `libfoo`, the `lib` section of the `Cargo.toml` file is specified as:

```
[package]
name = "libfoo"
[lib]
name = "foo"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

I have tried all permutations of libfoo and foo to see if Cargo is getting confused between the lib name and the package/directory name.

It also fails if I specify a local path to the dependency. (Cargo compiles the dependency but then claims not to find it when it is declared/imported in `lib.rs`.)

```
[dependencies]
libfoo = { path = "/Users/me/dev/libfoo" }
```

If I include a crate from git or the file system that has the same `[lib]` name as the `[package]` name, it works fine. So it appears the problem is with crates that have a have a library (`[lib]`) name that is different from the package (`[package]`) name.

If I remove the `[lib]` section from the dependency's `Cargo.toml` file, it works.

**Update**:  if `crate-type = ["cdylib"]` is removed from `libfoo`, this works with `foo` imported.   If that is there, I get the same error with `extern crate foo;`.

Comment: What do you mean with `try to use it`? Does the dependent project actually build ok, as you mentioned in the previous sentence?

Comment: Also note that the [docs](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories) actually suggest specifying a dependency from a GitHub repository like `{ git = "https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rand" }`.

Comment: @E_net4 that works for public repos, but for private repos you must use the ssh url.    That portion of it works ok.  The ssh url isn't documented.

Comment: `libmylib` is confuse... please use something more clear or the true name. Have you try `libmy` (I don't know just a idea) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cargo is interested in *package names* when it comes to dependencies, while the compiler (`rustc`) is interested in *library names* when it comes to loading their metadata and linking with them.

Let's take a look again at this `Cargo.toml` excerpt:

```
[package]
name = "libfoo"

[lib]
name = "foo"
```

Here, the *package name* is `libfoo` and the *library name* is `foo`.

When you want to declare a dependency on `libfoo` in your project, you need to write the *package name* (`libfoo`) in the `[dependencies]` table. For example:

```
[dependencies]
libfoo = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/me/libfoo", branch = "dev" }
```

This is what you already have, and it's correct.

However, when you want to import the library in your crate, you need to write the *library name* in the `extern crate` item, i.e.

```
extern crate foo;
```

---

How did I figure this out? First, I wrote `libfoo` in both `Cargo.toml` and the `extern crate` item, as you described. When I ran `cargo build`, I noticed that `libfoo` was built successfully, indicating that Cargo correctly resolved the dependency. But I also noticed that the compiler couldn't find `libfoo`, as you experienced.

I then inspected the command line passed to `rustc` by running `cargo build --verbose`. This is what I saw (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
Running `rustc [...] --extern foo=/[path]/target/debug/deps/libfoo-5cf876c5c8ac1bfb.rlib`
```

The `--extern name=path` argument tells `rustc` that the crate named `name` is located in `path`. The name here is `foo`, so we must write `extern crate foo;` in the code to reference it.

Comment: I did try `extern crate foo`.  Some more digging, `foo` works if `crate-type = ["cdylib"]` is absent.   But if it is there, I get the same error.  I'm assuming something is wrong, so I opened an issue on the cargo project.

Comment: I would argue that this is completely normal. `cdylib` represents a library that presents a C interface, not a Rust interface. A `cdylib` doesn't contain the metadata necessary to use `extern crate` on it, so Cargo doesn't even pass `--extern` to `rustc` for such dependencies. If you want a C interface *and* a Rust interface, use `crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]` instead (or `crate-type = ["cdylib", "dylib"]` if you want a dynamic library). If you just need a Rust interface, omit `crate-type`.